# Is there a way to rename std_logic_vector to a shorter name like 'v'?

Tags: vhdl

Personally, I get sick of typing std_logic_vector in VHDL code... it's too long... how can I alias the type name 'std_logic_vector' to a shorter name like 'v' for vector:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
entity dsn is
end entity dsn;
architecture beh of dsn is

    type v is std_logic_vector;

    signal mysig1 : v(7 downto 0);
    signal mysig2 : v(14 downto 0);

begin

end architecture;
```

Comment: Don't do it. Any future reader will be confused, including yourself in two months or even weeks after doing another project. Code is read much more often than written. Look into professional sources for comparison.

Comment: Besides  maintainability using  aliases or subtypes declared in a package  increase the threat surface for errors. There are editors with language specific macros. I use TextMate on a Mac with a VHDL package that allows me to write `slv` followed by a tab producing `std_logic_vector(x downto 0) ;` I don't use such macros, its as fast to write `std_logic_vector` as to invoke a macro. There are editors with pull down menus with the drawback of taking your hand off the keyboard home position.

Answer (score 2):

1. Use an alias

```vhdl
alias v is std_logic_vector;
```

2. Use a subtype

```vhdl
subtype x is v(open);
subtype x32 is x(31 downto 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do better with named subtypes that reflect the purpose of the signal

```
subtype data is std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
subtype addr is unsigned(19 downto 0);
```

in a package used by everything in your design. Now, declarations are not only shorter, but contain more useful information.